# Wpf TreeView Binding To ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, binding

Я попытался привязать TreeView к ObservableCollection. Но при заполнении ObservableCollection данные в TreeView не обновляются. Объясните, пожалуйста, почему?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewBindingToObservableCollection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TreeViewBindingToObservableCollection"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <l:ViewModelMainWindow x:Key="viewModelMainWindow" />

<!-- стиль для редактируемого поля в дереве -->
    <Style x:Key="EditableContentControl"
        TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="2,3" Text="{Binding Path=InnerText, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                    AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}"
                    Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox
                                Margin="-3,0,0,0"
                                Text="{Binding Path=InnerText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

<!-- шаблон для отображаемого элемента коллекции (класс l:Item) -->
    <DataTemplate
        DataType="{x:Type l:Item}">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="1" Padding="1"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Orientation="Horizontal" Background="PaleGoldenrod">
                <TextBlock Margin="10,3">Name:</TextBlock>
                <ContentControl
                    Content="{Binding Path=Name}"
                    Style="{StaticResource EditableContentControl}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource viewModelMainWindow}"/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <TreeView
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModelMainWindow.cs

```
namespace TreeViewBindingToObservableCollection
{
class ViewModelMainWindow
{
    public CollectionItems Items { get; private set; }

    public ViewModelMainWindow()
    {
        Items = new CollectionItems();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Item item = new Item();
            // вот здесь должно бы свойство обновиться,
            // но этого не происходит (???)
            item.Name = "Item " + i;

            Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Items.cs

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TreeViewBindingToObservableCollection
{
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    { 
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}

class CollectionItems : ObservableCollection<Item> { }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас в `EditableContentControl` биндинги стоят `Path=InnerText`, такого свойства нет ни у кого. Посмотрите повнимательнее цепочку биндингов. Не нужно в шаблоне элемента дерева делать привязку контента к `Item.Name` - вы так не сможете сделать потом двустороннюю привязку, так как в шаблон данных попадет просто строка.

Answer (score 1):

Да, что-то с биндингами вы намудрили. Скорее всего, для `ContentControl` вам достаточно забиндить целиком текущий элемент `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ...>`, а уже в шаблоне биндить для конкретных контролов свойство: `<TextBlock Margin="2,3" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />` и тоже самое для `TextBox`.

`Mode=TwoWay` - не нужно. Для `TextBlock` оно бессмысленно, а для `TextBox` по умолчанию TwoWay.